# why do i keep seeing nginx index.html on localhost when i run my docker image

Tags: docker, nginx

I installed and run `nginx` on my linux machine to understand the configurations etc. After a while i decided to remove it safely by following this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235347/what-is-the-best-way-to-uninstall-nginx) in order to use it in `docker`

---

By following [this documentaion](https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/tips-for-deploying-nginx-official-image-with-docker/) i run this command

1. `sudo docker run --name ngix -d -p 8080:80 pillalexakis/myrestapi:01`
   And i saw **ngix**'s homepage  at `localhost`
2. Then i **deleted** all `ngix` images & stopped all containers and i also run this command

   `sudo docker system prune -a`

---

But now restarted my service by this command
`sudo docker run -p 192.168.2.9:7777:8085 phillalexakis/myfirstapi:01` and i keep seeing at `localhost`  **ngix** `index.html`

How can i totally remove it ?

**Note:** I'm new with `docker` and i might have missed a lot of things. Let me know what extra `docker` commands should i run in order provide better information.

Comment: `docker system prune` doesn't stop running containers - your original container is probably still running, mapping its port 8080 to your localhost:80

Comment: `docker ps -a` is empty though

Comment: so you have no running containers and you still get the nginx start page when browsing port 80 localhost?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Try grep'ing the process for port `:80` by `ss --tcp --listening --process | grep ":80"` and then `ps -p <PID>`. That should help you identify it. It does sound as though you've still got a container running.

Comment: any chance that you changed `docker context`, or that (somehow) `sudo` is looking at a different one?

Comment: highly unlikely that i changed `docker context` , only by mistake but i doubt it

Comment: @DazWilkin I will provide more feedback soon

Comment: @JoshE "your original container is probably still running, mapping its port 8080 to your localhost:80" - `-p 8080:80` maps the host port 8080 to the container port 80 not the inverse.

Comment: `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':80'` to figure out if something is actually listening on port 80 then `ps -ef |grep <PID>` (replacing <PID> with the process ID bound to port 80). If there is a process running you might be able to `kill` it (know what you're doing, don't blindly `kill` processes), if it's a `docker` container (i.e. `... LISTEN      6234/docker-proxy`) then you could `docker stop` the container. If nothing is bound to the port then it's probably your browser caching the `index.html` (purge the browsers cache / test in incognito mode).

Comment: remember i see `ngix` at `localhost` only when i run my `docker` image

Comment: @masseyb - d'oh of course. In that case, since the nginx page is showing on port 80 localhost when container is running, there's either some goofy host name mapping in play, you have some proxy running, etc... You're not using LCOW are you?

Comment: OP is your browser configured to proxy connections on port 80 to port 8080 maybe?

Comment: uhm, how can i test that out?

Comment: Proxy settings are browser specific i.e. [firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox), [chrome](https://www.expressvpn.com/support/troubleshooting/google-chrome-no-proxy/), ...

Comment: @masseyb  i just run the image and `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':80'` returns nothing... i haven't manually configured any kind of proxy settings , unless `nginx` did it on it's own

Comment: @masseyb i even see `nginx` homepage at `192.168.2.9` which is my internal `IP`, plus the image is not available at `7777` . That's how i run it `sudo docker run -p 192.168.2.9:7777:8085 phillalexakis/myfirstapi:01`.

Comment: I'm so confused right now

Comment: Confusing me as well. What's the output of `docker ps` while the container is running? Can you add your user to the `docker` group (i.e. `sudo usermod -a -G docker username`) and stop using `sudo`? `nginx` wouldn't configure any proxy settings on it's own, a copy of your `nginx.conf` might help though. Isn't i.e. a work computer pre-installed / configured for you is it?

Comment: @masseyb , there is no `nginx` image running when i run my container... `docker ps` returns just the **REST API** container

Comment: @masseyb yes i will add my user to `docker` group

Comment: Note than running the `image` in another machine in another network doesn't show any `nginx` home pages... runs just **REST API** !

Comment: So, running `image` on my machine `=` `nginx_index_html` at `localhost` ,  on any other runs `ok`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your host have been preparing as below

- your files (index.html, js, etc) under folder - /myhost/nginx/html
- your nginx configuration                      - /myhost/nginx/nginx.conf

Solution

1. map your files (call volume) on the fly from outside docker image via docker cli

This is the command

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web \
      -v /myhost/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html \
      -v /myhost/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
      nginx
```

2. copy your files into docker image by build your own docker image via Dockerfile

This is your Dockerfile under /myhost/nginx

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./html/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

This is the command to build your docker image

```
cd /myhost/nginx
docker build -t pillalexakis/nginx .
```

This is the command to run your docker image

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web \
       pillalexakis/nginx
```

Comment: No problem, you're welcome.